# Is it possible to animate Fontastic custom icon?

Tags: css, animation, fontastic

### What I want to do

I made custom icons (e.g. `icon-plus-circle`) using Fontastic and I've been trying to animate them. When I hover over the `icon-plus-circle` I want it to get bigger. I tried to do that using `font`, but it didn't work.

My question is: it is possible to animate custom icons?

If someone could help me animate these custom icons that would be very much appreciated!

### My code

*HTML*

```
<div class="student-row">
    <div class="student-box student-box-add">
        <button type="button" class="icon-plus-circle" aria-label="Add student"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.icon-plus-circle {
    color: #02C8A7;
    transition-property: font;
        -webkit-transition-property: font;
        -moz-transition-property: font;
        -o-transition-property: font;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

icon-plus-circle:hover{
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/6mpL7odk/1/)

Comment: You just have a typo. `.icon-plus-circle:hover` is missing the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your css class was not activating on hover was because you forgot to place a period in front of the class.

So this:

```
    icon-plus-circle:hover{
      font-size: 5em;
}
```

Should be this:

```
   .icon-plus-circle:hover{
      font-size: 5em;
}
```

I fixed it for you in this js-fiddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/uthvam65/